# How to fix “ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH” error that happens only on some devices?

Tags: ssl, encryption, dns, render, mismatch

I recently published both a React application and a nodejs web service on render.com. Additionally, I purchased a domain from GoDaddy and set up a custom domain for my React application on Render, using that domain, and a custom domain for the web service, using a subdomain of that domain.

I can access both domains with no issues from most devices, but in other devices I get the “ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH” error. I've checked my domain's certificate, TLS version, cipher suite, and everything is as it's supposed to be. I don't know what else to check and/or do to fix this issue, since I really need to access those applications from those devices.

Comment: Would you be comfortable sharing the URL? Also, are you sure you checked the settings of the actual server the client connects to, including load balancer/CDN?

Comment: Also, you need to be more specific as to which devices fail to connect (including OS versions if applicable).

Comment: If it only happens on some devices, that implies that the server doesn't support weaker ciphers of older browsers on those devices.   If you want to confirm (for a publicly available website), check the handshake results (using SSL Labs server test) to confirm there is no common cipher between the device (client-side) and the server-side for the handshake to land on.

Comment: You may check this post https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/ssl-tips-how-to-fix-err_ssl_protocol_error/ for more information. There are few things that you can test.

Answer (score 2):

*This is just a guess until more information is given, but it's an educated guess.*

During a TLS handshake, the client offers a range of protocol versions and cipher suites. The server then picks from these options to continue the handshake, but if it doesn't support any combination of the versions and ciphers, it returns `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`.

This usually happens when either the server or the client are very strict, due to security (only strong versions/ciphers are allowed), or the software is outdated (and doesn't support newer versions/ciphers).

Specifically to render.com, it seems that it does not allow configuring TLS [cipher suites](https://community.render.com/t/configuration-of-tls-security-suites/3328) or [protocol versions](https://community.render.com/t/disable-tls-1-0-and-1-1/5322). And [scanning a sample app](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=flask.onrender.com&latest) shows that Render's web servers only support TLS 1.2 and 1.3, with surprisingly few cipher suites for TLS 1.2. According to SSL Labs this would fail in Safari 8 or earlier (are the problematic devices perhaps old iPhones?).

There are three solutions:

- Open a ticket with render.com to support more cipher suites (at the cost of security).
- Ask your clients to update to a newer browser.
- Add another server in-between, with more forgiving settings. This could be a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) like Cloudflare or Akamai.